# org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.struts.action.ActionServletWrapper

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, jackson, struts-1

I am trying to see how much work will be involved if we migrate our legacy Struts 1.x web app to AngularJS + Java RESTful Web Service. (I know that Struts 1.x doesn't fit nicely with AngularJS.)

The first thing that I notice is that there are so many Struts `ActionForm` and I was wondering if there is any easier way to get response in JSON format. So we have class like this a lot:

```java
public class Note extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm{

//setter and getter...
}
```

I tried to convert this to POJO style class and then so much other changes are needed for DAO, helper, utility classes as well. Is this something inevitable? Or is it better to migrate to Struts 2 first and then try to adopt AngularJS?

By the way, I get this error in Eclipse console when I tried to get response:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
No serializer found for class 
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServletWrapper and 
no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEAS)
(through reference chain: org.kki.dao.oracle.ads.TranscribedNote["servletWrapper"])
```

**Update:**

```java
@Path("/note")
public class NoteRestService {


@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Note [] getNote() {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
     NoteDAO noteDao = new NoteDAO(null);
     Note[] note = noteDao.selectNote(user.getUserId());

  return note;
}
}
```

**AngularJS code:**

```js
myApp.controller('noteCtrl', ['$scope', 'Note',

   function ($scope, Note) {

var vm = this;
$scope.noteLists = Note.query(function(){
    
    vm.noteList = $scope.noteLists;
});


myApp.factory('Note', ['$resource',
function($resource) {

    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/angular_demo/rest/note/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
                   
        get: {method: 'GET', cache: false, isArray: false}
      
    });
   
 }]);
```

Comment: How did you return response in json format?

Comment: I just edited my original question.

Comment: The answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You got errors because `Note` object extends `ActionForm`. So you have inherited properties that should not be serialized. Just remove dependency for the `Note` class

```
public class Note {

//setter and getter...
}
```